# Destructing parameter array php

Tags: php

I've been looking but unfortunately not found anything useful.

I have a function

```
function myFunc ($param1, $param2){ ...
```

I need to call that function but I have the parameters in an array

```
$params = [$param1, $param2]
```

Is there any way of doing something like `...[]` (like in Js) ?

**Note**: I can not do

```
myFunc($params[$param1], $params[$param2]);
```

Answer (score 6):

Since **php5.6** there's a [`...` syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics):

```
myFunc(...$params);
```

And of course, [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) still exists and works both in php5 and php7:

```
call_user_func_array('myFunc', $params);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `call_user_func_array` documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

```
$params = [$param1, $param2]

function myFunc ($param1, $param2){
    echo $param1;
    echo $param2;
}

call_user_func_array('myFunc', $params);
```